# Does Japser Reports work with Java9

Tags: java, jasper-reports, java-9

Im having trouble using Japser Reports with Java 9.

My JasperVersions:

```
 <dependency.version.jasper>6.5.1</dependency.version.jasper>
```

When trying to build my Report i get the following error Message:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Building report".
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: my/path/to/my/class/User has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

the Error occurrs probbably because Jasper does not Support java 9 Classes. I cant find any information on this topic, does anyone have a Idea how to write a workaround or did i do some other mistake?

EDIT:

After searching some more i realised that the problem only happens when im in the Designer in Eclipse, so it is most likely that eclipse itselve is not running in a JVM 9. I checked for the current version of java installed and it is java9, when i change the eclipse.ini file from:

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
```

to

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.9
```

i get a incompatible jvm error which says that im trying to start it with 1.8.0_161. How do i change my settings that my eclipse is acutally using my current JDK?

RESOLVED:
The error was that my Eclipse itselve only run in Java8. So my Application was building everything in Java9, like i wanted it to, but when i was inside the jasperReports Designer, the designer itselve run in java8. Thats why it crashed. The solution was to change the systemvariables and put my JavaPath over the Oracle JavaPath that for some reason had a higher priority.

Comment: The error message states that class "de/lmis/smartpp/entity/model/User" was compiled with a newer version of Java, which the older version of the Java Virtual Machine where it's running doesn't recognize. Are you sure that class belongs to Jasper Reports? it doesn't look so...

Comment: Yes the "User" is from my project which is build with JAVA9 i thought that the error was that the class i use in my report is build in java 9 but Jasper Reports can only handel Java8 Classes.

Comment: If your code was compiled using Java 8, then it should work in a Java 9 JVM, but not necessarily the other way (which is what the error message shows, "class file version 53.0 corresponds to Java 9, and 52.0 to Java 8)

Comment: my code is compiled using java9 and it runs in a Java9 JVM, everything except building JasperReports is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Code was compiled in Java version 9 but executed in Java 8 JVM, which not necessarily works. Try compiling it in Java 8, or executing it in Java 9 JVM.

Comment: my code runs in a Java 9 JVM and is build with a Java9, but the error happens only when im in the designer of Jasper and try to hit the buildReport Button, could it be that my Eclipse does not run in Java 9 and that thats the problem?

Comment: If you use iReports designer you can check which One uses  like this: https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/changing-version-java-used-ireport